# Finding a pair of entries that are out of order

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that returns the number of pairs that are out of order.

For example, this function would return `6` for the argument `'DCBA'`.

My code so far is:

```
def calc_out_of_order_pairs(s):
    res = []
    sum = 0
    for i in s:
        for j in s:
            res.append(i+j)

    for test in res:
        if pair[0] > pair[1]:
            sum +=1

    return sum
```

Comment: recommended reading: http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> sum(x>y for x,y in combinations("DCBA",2))
6
```

Hint: Using combinations like this returns each pair where the first in the pair occurs earlier in the string than the second

```
>>> list(combinations("DCBA", 2))
[('D', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'A'), ('B', 'A')]
```

Here is an alternate way which might be easier for beginners to follow

```
>>> s = "DCBA"
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in range(len(s)-1):
...   for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
...     if s[i]>s[j]:
...       count += 1
... 
>>> count
6
```

Comment: Excellent answer. `itertools.combinations()` is available starting in Python 2.6.

Comment: is there a simpler way to solve this problem? I just started learning Python.

Comment: @user1021090: the thing is that you're dealing with mathematical concepts, so using things like combinations, list-comprehensions or summations is the way to go. Study the tutorial to feel confortable with the language. However, I'd recommend not to use the Python's implicit conversion True->1, False->0: `sum((1 if x>y else 0) for (x, y) in combinations("DCBA", 2))`

Comment: @user1021090, I've added a way to do it using nested loops. It doesn't hurt to mention you are a beginner in the question, then you will find you get simpler and more detailed answers

Comment: correction to my own comment, this is more clear: sum(1 for (x, y) in combinations("DCBA", 2) if x > y)